# How to access domain information on a node in SCIP?

Tags: scip

I am now solving MILP (mixed integer linear programming) with SCIP. When the branch-and-bound tree grows, there are lots of subproblems in the tree tagged as SCIP_Node.

How can I access the domain infomation on the subproblem (SCIP_Node) as I was trying to sample some feasible solutions (might not be optimal) on this subproblem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a question on SCIP, a solver for mixed interger programming.

Answer (score 0):

and sorry for the late answer.

You have to be aware that SCIP does not solve the whole subproblem in each `SCIP_NODE`. So, while a node is "active", you can access all the domain information for that node by calling, e.g. `SCIPvarGetLbLocal.

So when SCIP switches to a different node during solving, it computes the path to the new node in the tree and then applies all boundchanges along the way.
You could do the same if you have a `SCIP_NODE` that is not the focusnode.